# Problem with deb file. what is deb file?

Tags: deb

I have a Simple question, i'm new to the linux world.
I was looking in the web for some explanations But I have not found a good explanation.

What is deb file?
What is RPM file?

Thanks  :)

Comment: "But I have not found a good explanation." I seriously doubt that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager I *really* doubt that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.deb files are Packages for use under the Debian System.

.rpm files are for Packages under the use of the RedHat System.

If you're looking to download software, and you are running Ubuntu(Debian based) you will use a .deb package.

Comment: Note that ideally you should get the deb files through a package manager (e.g. `apt-get`), downloading random ones off the internet can sometimes make it more difficult and mess up your system